# Listen to WM_SYSCOMMAND Events

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wm-syscommand

I am writing a small c++ program that should react to the `sc_screensaver` and `sc_monitorpower` event.

this should run in background hence no gui is intended.

Since i have no experience with the windows api yet, i am struggling a lot with this.

A already googled a lot and found many approaches which either i dont understand or dont work.

Can anyone of you give me a hint?
I read its about catching the `wm_syscommand` but that seems to be difficult because i dont have a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get messages is by a message loop and a window procedure.

If your program does not have a visible gui, you have to create a [message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only) for that purpose, and your `main` must have the code to create it and to listen windows messages (note: "windows" here, refers to the system, not the gui).